# What is the std::partial_sum equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, std

In C#, what is the best equivalent of the C++ [std::partial_sum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum)?

Comment: No, try LINQ `Take` and `Sum`

Comment: In this context, what is your equivalent to OutputIterator and InputIterator?

Comment: @coding the std library is part of C++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operation appears to be a weak version of combining map (aka Select) and reduce (aka Aggregate) operations, restricted to a binary operation.  We can do better!

```
public static IEnumerable<R> MyAggregate<T, R>(
  this IEnumerable<T> items,
  R seed,
  Func<T, R, R> mapper) 
{
  R current = seed;      
  foreach(T item in items)
  {
    current = mapper(item, current);
    yield return current;
  }
}
```

And now your desired function is just a special case:

```
static IEnumerable<int> PartialSum(this IEnumerable<int> items) =>
  items.MyAggregate(0, (i, s) => s + i);
```

Commenter Tom Blodget points out that this requires that the sum operation have an identity; what if you don't have one? In that case you have to give up the ability to make the sum type different than the summand type:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> PartialSum<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> items,
  Func<T, T, T> sum)
{
  bool first = true;
  T current = default(T);
  foreach(T item in items) 
  {
    current = first ? item : sum(current, item);
    first = false;
    yield return current;
  }
}
```

And you can use it

```
myints.PartialSum((i, s) => i + s);
```

Comment: For `std::partial_sum`, the first result element is always the first source element. But for every possible mapper function, there isn't necessarily a seed where `mapper(items.First(), seed) == items.First()`. So, I think the first result element needs its own `yield return`. Of course, in the case of `(i, s) => s + i`, a seed of 0 works.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: why do you need that `R`?

Comment: @apocalypse: `cities.MyAggregate(0, (city, sum) => city.Population + sum)` -- there's no requirement that the sum type be the same type as the summands.

Comment: @EricLippert: OK, understand now :)

Comment: @apocalypse: Or suppose you're summing nullables and you want nulls to be zero.  `myNullableInts.MyAggregate(0, (i, s) => (i ?? 0) + s)`  so now the sum type and the summand type are again different.

Comment: @TomBlodget: That's a good point. If we don't have an identity then we have to give up the ability to have a different sum type than the summands.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] values = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var result = values.Select ((x, index) => values.Take (index + 1).Sum ());
```

Result: `1, 3, 6, 10`

But it is better to write own method if you care about performance.

**Edit:**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyAggregate<T> (this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, T, T> mapper)
{
    bool processingFirstElement = true;

    T accumulator = default (T);

    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        if (processingFirstElement)
        {
            processingFirstElement = false;
            accumulator = item;
        }
        else
        {
            accumulator = mapper (accumulator, item);
        }

        yield return accumulator;
    }
}
```

And now:

```
 int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

 var result = values.MyAggregate ((accumulator, item) => accumulator + item).ToList ();
```